# Microsoft Word 2010 stops responding after change the font type

Tags: microsoft-word, fonts

For some reason, Microsoft Word 2010 started having a problem.
When I try to change the font type (touch the arrow next to the font box) the program stops responding. Same thing happens when I try to print a document.
What should I do?

Comment: Is this the only program which you have this trouble?

Answer (score 0):

How many fonts do you have loaded/installed?

Windows has to enumerate all of them when you select the 'choose font' box.  It might just be thinking very very hard about fonts during this time.  Try waiting longer, see if it eventually responds.

Answer (score 0):

**This happens because of two reasons...**

1. Installing more fonts that it's capacity.
2. Not enough system memory. Try to increase memory by adding additional RAM
3. Your system memory is not enough for run MS Office 2010. If you like, downgrade MS Office 2010 to 2007.